# Google Cloud authentication error. Username does not match with json

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to upload a dockerfile to the Container Registry.

In order to to that, fist i have to set up authentication. And in order to do that, i have to have set up the application keys.

As far as the keys, i followed these instructions succesfully:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

I have managed to donwload the json files with the keys.

Now for the authentication part, i follow the steps here:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud-helper

I open the cloud shell (the terminal on the browser).
I type `gcloud auth login` i get a link, i open it, i copy and paste to the terminal a code, and this works fine.

Now i have to type the command that will authenticate me, locally to my system.

I type `gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE`

The KEY-FILE is the directory of the json.

ACCOUNT is the service account name in the format [USERNAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com. You can view existing service accounts on the Service Accounts page of Cloud Console or with the command gcloud iam service-accounts list

I get this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Invalid value for [ACCOUNT]: The given account name does not match the account name in the key file.  This argument can be omitted when using .json keys.`

So there is an error in the ACCOUNT.

First of all the PROJECT-ID is fine.

For USERNAME, i use: `FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME`. This is my prompt at the google shell (on the browser).
When i spawn a terminal, this is what i get `FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME@cloudshell`

So i omit the `@cloushell` part and get the part before it.

But it does not work. I open up the json and there are no fields that contain my username. These are the fields it has:

```
type
project_id
private_key_id
private_key
client_email
client_id
auth_uri
token_uri
auth_provider_x509_cert_url
client_x509_cert_url
```

The field project_id contains the PROJECT-ID.
But there is no mention of my USERNAME inside the json.

The field client_id contains some numbers.

I passed the email as well, i passed the client_id, but the error is the same.

Can someone help me, what/where is the correct USERNAME i have to provide in the gcloud command?

Comment: The service account identity (ACCOUNT) is the `client_email`. Read the error message again, you do not need to specify the ACCOUNT as the command will auto-find it.

Comment: I tried passing client_email, the client_email without '@' and the client_id, and i always get the same error.

Comment: Run this command `gcloud components update`.

Comment: You mean on my system right? Not on the gcloud shell (web). Am i correct?

Comment: Your question states: `locally to my system`. Run the command on the system that you are having problems with. The point is to make sure you are running the current version and not an old version.

Comment: You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is managed by an external package manager.
Please consider using a separate installation of the Cloud SDK created through the default mechanism described at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Comment: But i installed it yesterday.